# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, optional-chaining

I have been stuck on this error for an hour now and nothing i do seems to resolve it. What am i missing? Shouldn't the optional chaining on the array maping resolve this issue?

```
            <h2>Cart Items</h2>
            <div>
                {cartItems?.length === 0 && <div>Cart is empty</div>}
            </div>
            {cartItems?.map((e) => (
                <div key={e.id} className="row">/*error is on this line
                    <div className='col-2'>{e.name}</div>
                    <div className='col-2'>
                        {e.qty} x {e.qty*e.price.toFixed(2)}kr
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
```

Comment: There's no reference to `length` in your code provided. Are you debugging in the right place?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also see [ask] and [mre].

Comment: I am referencing to length further up in the code.

Comment: If the error says reading `length`, then it has nothing to do with `map` - it has to do with `length`. The part you've included does appear to be covered with optional chaining. Does the error include a stack trace or line number? I would guess that this is either not the right place in the code, or maybe you're using a cached version of the code?

Comment: Yes you were right! The `length` was the problem, i was just confused cause the error was pointing at a different line in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not thrown during mapping but while reading .length prop on cartItems array.

Answer (score -2):

I think the *optional-chaining* there ensures `cartItems` is not `null` but that doesn't mean there could be `null` values inside the Array.

For example: `[{ a: 1 }, null]` is valid but reading properties during the mapping will fail.

I would make sure `cartItems` is clean.